# Show price instead of quantity in shopping cart wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shopping-cart

On this website: https://www.stenenentegels.nl/

The shopping cart is in the top right corner of the website.
When it is not folded open it shows the quantity of the cart in the orange circle.
I want to show the price there instead of the quantity. Has someone a solution for this?

I used this plugin for the custom shopping cart: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-floating-cart-lite/

I think the best way to achieve this is to write a function in the functions.php file.

Hope you guys can help me out!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read up on how to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  You may also benefit from [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What is expected of SO users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 1):

i checked this
so what you have to change is:

copy this file:

> .../plugins/woo-floating-cart-lite/public/templates/parts/trigger.php

to (In the header of this file it is described)

> .../themes/yourtheme/woo-floating-cart/parts/trigger.php

In your copied file replace line 26 to 40 with:

```
$total_items = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
$icon_type = woofc_option('trigger_icon_type', 'image');

// Get Cart total price including tax
$ordertotal = wp_kses_data( WC()->cart->get_total() );
?>

<a href="#" class="woofc-trigger<?php echo (($total_items > 99) ? ' woofc-count-big' : '');?> woofc-icontype-<?php echo $icon_type;?>">

    <span class="<?php echo woofc_trigger_cart_icon_class();?>"></span>

    <ul class="woofc-count"> <!-- cart items count -->
        <li><?php echo ($ordertotal);?></li>
        <li><?php echo ($total_items + 1);?></li>
    </ul> <!-- .count -->

    <span class="<?php echo woofc_trigger_close_icon_class();?>"></span>
</a>
```

You should do this is an child theme ofcourse!

Comment: Thanks for replying this fast!
Next week I am able to test it than you will hear from me ;)

Comment: I updated like you said but it still shows the quantity instead of the price